# groovy - replace values in json when loading from jmx

Tags: groovy, replace, jmx

I have a piece a code as below. This is loading data from JMX to monitoring tool. Unfortunately, there are some 'NaN' values, which are not read properly by monitoring tool, and this interrupts transfer. My intention is to replace 'on fly' values 'NaN' to 'null'.
Has anybody any idea how to do it?

BR

```
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;

def hostName = hostProps.get("system.hostname")
def jmxPort = "10002"
def query = "Hadoop:service=hiveserver2,name=hiveserver2"

def metricsURL = "http://${hostName}:${jmxPort}/jmx?qry=${query}"
def ad = true

public class FetchMetrics implements PrivilegedAction {

  def url;

  public FetchMetrics(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public Object run() {
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    def con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
    return con.getInputStream();
  }
}

lc = new LoginContext("Client");
lc.login();
Subject subject = lc.getSubject();

PrivilegedAction action = new FetchMetrics(metricsURL);
def metrics = Subject.doAsPrivileged(subject, action, null);

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def deviceMetrics = jsonSlurper.parse(metrics)


// Hit out endpoint and get our metrics
//deviceMetrics = jsonSlurper.parse(new URL(metricsURL))


deviceMetrics.'beans'[0].each {
    println it
}

return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to use LAX json slurper, however it will parse `NaN` as a string `"NaN"`...

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonParserType
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().setType( JsonParserType.LAX )
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "a":111, "b": NaN}')


println new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString()
```

prints

```
{
    "a": 111,
    "b": "NaN"
}
```

Comment: hello, unfortunately, monitoring tool is not recognizing JsonParserType type, so I must find another workaround...

Comment: did you import it? `import groovy.json.JsonParserType`